# setting password to an individual Database in my sql

Tags: java, php, mysql

I want to  set a password '1234' for a database (suppose 'DB1') &  '4567' for another database ('DB2'). Is this possible in mysql or xaamp

Comment: Yes. every connection has its own username and password. You can use the same usernames and passwords for connections to the same database or different databases as you wish.

Comment: considering you have xammp install. You should open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ click on databases tab thn you can edit privileges for each database.

Answer (score 1):

You can create in phpmyadmin or in the mysql console users which have their own permissions and can access some databases.

```
CREATE USER user_specification
    [, user_specification] ...

user_specification:
    user [IDENTIFIED BY [PASSWORD] 'password']
```

See also the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html)

And also the grand command:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in php myadmin

[image]

click on the  check privileges

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. In `PHPMyAdmin` you have such an option; for each database you can give your own password.